# Passing waypoint info to comgooglemaps (Google Maps URL Scheme)

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I am in the process of creating an app using the Google Maps api to generate random biking routes (http://sutsurikeru.com/maps) and it works fine so far, but the issue I am having is passing the generated route, including the following info to the google maps app:

1. Start Destination
2. Way-point (randomly generated using https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25877/how-to-generate-random-locations-nearby-my-location)
3. End Destination (same as the start destination)

Once I've got all the lat/long information I pass it to a button that is created when the route is generated so that it can pass the route to the Google Maps App, but I am unsure how to pass the way-point as there is no mention of it in the docs - https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/urlscheme

```
$('#goRide').append('<a class="goridebtn" href="comgooglemaps://?saddr=' + address + '&daddr=' + address + '&directionsmode=bicycling">Go ride</a>');
```

I guess my question is then, can I include the way-point information when I am passing it to the Google Maps App?

Comment: If the scheme doesn't support the waypoint param, then I'm afraid it's impossible to pass it to the app.

Comment: That sucks then! I'll have to remove that functionality from my prototype until it's supported

Comment: This has been logged with Googles Issue tracking - no eta on a fix date but it has been accepted - https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=10392

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i couldn't find the answer for that too , so i ended using:

"**comgooglemapsurl**" instead..

this way you can pass a full url (same onese used in the browser)
the format will be something like this:

```
comgooglemapsurl://www.google.com/maps/dir/STARTING_POINT/WAYPOINT_1/WAYPOINT_2/WAYPOINT_3/WAYPOINT_4/DESTINATION
```

you can add as many points as u wish

```
comgooglemapsurl://www.google.com/maps/dir/24.848607,46.660478/24.748607,46.760478/24.778607,46.784478
```

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/ios-urlscheme

Comment: Has this documentation always been there? Looking at the updated time-stamp, its been updated as of today 05/06/2017!

Comment: not sure since when this was added, i just bumped to this issue today and it took me couple of googling hours until i found this

Comment: Well it worked for me haha, my app is complete after 8 months of waiting!

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you can add waypoints using the `+to:` variable inside the daddr text. The following example shows this in use:

```
comgooglemapsurl://?saddr=55.852866,-4.323120&daddr=56.019015,-3.372803+to:55.972934,-3.279419+to:55.932952,-3.284912+to:56.022085,-3.565063
```

Comment: Happy days! I will test this as soon as I get home from work!.I also noticed they updated their documentation but there is no mention of "+to" yet

Comment: Did you have any joy with this?

Comment: No it didn't work, but i haven't tried since I posted my response!

Comment: Hmm, this works for me. I did notice that I had stated `comgooglemaps` rather than `comgooglemapsurl` above, so ensure that is correct.